# Forecasting accuracy of VECM using train and test

Tags: forecasting, multivariate-analysis, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model, train-test-split

I am forecasting using VECM and I plan to do it on train and test split data. My data is 132 monthly observations. My VECM is lag 3 with unrestricted constant. All diagnostic test are passed.

I plan to do test and train on my data with 70% 30% split. However, when I use this model on my train data, there is no cointegration on this specification. Should I do another cointegration test on my train data and forecast the future 40 observation then check the accuracy using my test or just use the original specification of my VECM on the train then check the accuracy on the test? Thank you.